# EF & MVC: Same database, different queries

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have a peculiar case where I have a dev. and a staging server for an MVC application.  I made some updates to dev, everything is great, when I publish it up to the staging server, I get some weird errors when using EF to talk to the database.

I have tracked the problem to the fact that the EF calls are producing different SQL depending  on the server.  I have confirmed that the code is the same, and that the database connection is also the same, so why is there a difference in the queries?

The only thing that is different on the two servers is the web.config files.  The web.config does not get sent up at publish time.  This makes me think that there is some configuration stuff in there that is the cause of all of this trouble.  All I can see that is related to EF is the same in both files, so I'm not really sure.

What could be the cause of the differences ?

Here is the working version from dev:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Extent1].[theID] AS [theID], 
[Extent1].[otherID] AS [otherID], 
[Extent1].[field1] AS [field1], 
[Extent1].[field2] AS [field2], 
[Extent1].[field3] AS [field3], 
[Extent1].[field4] AS [field4], 
[Extent1].[field5] AS [field5], 
[Extent1].[field6] AS [field6], 
[Extent1].[field7] AS [field7], 
[Extent2].[field8] AS [field8], 
[Extent2].[field9] AS [field9], 
[Extent2].[field10] AS [field10]
FROM   [dbo].[table1] AS [Extent1]
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT 
      [view1].[field8] AS [field8], 
      [view1].[field9] AS [field9], 
      [view1].[field10] AS [field10]
      FROM [dbo].[view1] AS [view1]) AS [Extent2] ON ([Extent2].[field8] = [Extent1].[field8]) AND ([Extent1].[field8] IS NOT NULL)
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT 
      [view1].[field8] AS [field8], 
      [view1].[field9] AS [field9], 
      [view1].[field10] AS [field10]
      FROM [dbo].[view1] AS [view1]) AS [Extent3] ON ([Extent3].[field8] = [Extent1].[field8]) AND ([Extent1].[field8] IS NOT NULL)
WHERE ([Extent1].[theID] = @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[field3] = @p__linq__1)',N'@p__linq__0 int,@p__linq__1 varchar(8000)',@p__linq__0=1,@p__linq__1='searchVal'
```

and the broken, non working one from the staging server.

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Extent1].[theID] AS [STORE_ID], 
[Extent1].[otherID] AS [otherID], 
[Extent1].[field1] AS [field1], 
[Extent1].[field2] AS [field2], 
[Extent1].[field3] AS [field3], 
[Extent1].[field4] AS [field4], 
[Extent1].[field5] AS [field5], 
[Extent1].[field6] AS [field6], 
[Extent1].[field7] AS [field7], 
[Join1].[field81] AS [field8], 
[Join1].[field9] AS [field9], 
[Join1].[field10] AS [field10], 
[Join3].[otherID] AS [otherID1]
FROM   [dbo].[table1] AS [Extent1]
LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent2].[field8] AS [field81], [Extent2].[field9] AS [field9], [Extent2].[field10] AS [field10]
    FROM  (SELECT 
      [view1].[field8] AS [field8], 
      [view1].[field9] AS [field9], 
      [view1].[field10] AS [field10]
      FROM [dbo].[view1] AS [view1]) AS [Extent2]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[table1] AS [Extent3] ON ([Extent3].[field8] IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent2].[field8] = [Extent3].[field8]) ) AS [Join1] ON [Extent1].[field8] = [Join1].[field81]
LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent4].[field8] AS [field82], [Extent5].[otherID] AS [otherID]
    FROM  (SELECT 
      [view1].[field8] AS [field8], 
      [view1].[field9] AS [field9], 
      [view1].[field10] AS [field10]
      FROM [dbo].[view1] AS [view1]) AS [Extent4]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[table1] AS [Extent5] ON ([Extent5].[field8] IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent4].[field8] = [Extent5].[field8]) ) AS [Join3] ON [Extent1].[field8] = [Join3].[field82]
WHERE ([Extent1].[STORE_ID] = @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[field3] = @p__linq__1)',N'@p__linq__0 int,@p__linq__1 varchar(8000)',@p__linq__0=1,@p__linq__1='searchVal'
```

As you can see, one has a bunch of extra joins, etc, so what the heck is going on?

Comment: "some weird errors" - please explain.

Comment: without the error details and difference in queries you are mentioning it is difficult to guess.

Comment: The queries are different.  One has extra joins, the other does not.  Since the code and connections are all the same, I don't really see how the queries are revelent.

Comment: @Mitul There, I added the queries.